# Recommend a good mongodb/database tutorial for a beginner?

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm a designer; proficient at HTML/CSS/JQuery. I know next to nothing about databases. I'm interested in learning mongodb (it seems simpler), but can't find any tutorials that will hold my hand from start to finish. Most tutorials I've found teach you how to use it in the command line or in their own web based shell. I'm looking for something that will show me how to actually deploy a site using it.

Or, if mongodb isn't appropriate for a database novice, then can you recommend some database tutorial that will be good for what I'm looking for?

Comment: If you really want to learn something that will help you the most in your career - learn a relational database.  MySQL is free and very widely used.  Because relational databases and MySQL are so widely used, you will find many tutorials.  MongoDB is great for specific purposes.  However, it will rarely help you in your career and is often the wrong choice for storing well structured and related data.

Comment: http://www.inmongodb.net/p/mongodb-tutorials.html  it gives you the basic  knowledge. i started my MongoDB from here

Comment: I feel the path to understanding starts from the overview (the bigger picture) of the subject and then strategically focusing down to individual pillars of fundamental concepts. So I would recommend to start at Glossary of MongoDB which will give you a fuller picture of its capabilities. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-init-script

Comment: MongoDB docs have all that is required in a lucid manner. If you are looking for some examples, I would like to recommend https://www.tutorialkart.com/mongodb/mongodb-tutorial/

Answer (score 6):

Here are a couple of great sources that I have checked while docummenting to create a course:

### A grasp of classic Relational Databases:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/relational-databases-for-dummies/

### And continue with visual creation of Databases:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/visual-database-creation-with-mysql-workbench/

### Next, you can go deeper in SQL knowledge:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-2/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/

### Now, get to know the non-Relational "NoSQL" world:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/getting-started-with-mongodb/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/getting-started-with-mongodb-part-2/

> Note: You can go directly to the MongoDB/NoSQL part directly, but I
>   recommend at least reviewing the first link (Relational Databases) to
>   get a good knowledge of the pros and cons of both paradigms.

p.s. I'm not part of tutsplus.com nor related to them. IMO, these matters are really well explained there

Answer (score 4):

> Most tutorials I've found teach you how to use it in the command line or in their own web based shell. I'm looking for something that will show me how to actually deploy a site using it.

This is basically where MongoDB starts. It's not really at the level of MySQL or SQL Server where you click a few buttons and have everything magically working.

The tutorials will start you at the command-line so that you can do basic CRUD (Create/Read/Update/Delete). Then you'll need to learn the specific details for whatever language you're using on the web-server (PHP, Ruby, C#, etc.)

There are tutorials for getting started (installing MongoDB on your server, installing drivers, etc). But you'll have to let us know what language you're using in the back end.

---

PHP has a ton of "getting started" documentation.

Here's a good [link of links](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/578814979/mongodb-and-php-resources). Here's one of the links with [basic wrapper code](http://query7.com/mongodb-php-tutorial). And here's a [link with an extensive example](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/118-Developing-scalable-PHP-applications-using-MongoDB.html).

You'll probably find that the PHP code is very similar to the shell. You use `array('_id' => 'bob')` instead of `{ _id: 'bob'}` and `db->coll->find()` instead of `db.coll.find()`.

Comment: Thanks Gates. I suppose the language that I have the most familiarity with (and that's not much) is php.

Comment: @alex One don't have to use programming language to learn MongoDB. Either command line can be used or GUI based tool like RoboMongo can be used if you want to see things graphically to focus on understanding your structure instead of syntax.